# how to resolve "Attribute android: ~ is not allowed here" in android app?

Tags: android, dart

When I run device(emulator) in android studio, it occures some error like below pictures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h6Dx.png)

I attached code below.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.egolium">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
   <application
        android:label="egolium"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            >
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"></meta-data>
<!--                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"-->
<!--                android:value="{admob_appId}"-->
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried restart in the menu that 'invalidate cache', but it still be same.
or when I remove the codes, it occures more errors

Could you let me know why it occures and how to resolve these?